# Yii Framework: Specifying defaultScheme in URL Validator

Tags: yii, url-validation

I'm sure this is straightforward, but I can't figure it out. I'm trying to set a [defaultScheme](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlValidator#defaultScheme-detail) to the Yii URL validator in my model, so that it accepts addresses like www.something.com as well as http://www.something.com.

To do this, I'm using the following code:

```
...
array('website', 'url', 'defaultScheme' => 'http://'),
...
```

This doesn't seem to be working, and I still get an "Website is not a valid URL" error when trying to update. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just http

http is the scheme name, whereas http:// is the scheme plus the beginning of the "hierarchical part"

Answer (score 0):

```
array('website', 'url', 'defaultScheme' => 'http')
```